# How to create a DataFrame with index names different from `row` and write data into (`index`, `column`) pairs in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

How can I create a DataFrame with Julia with index names that are different from `Row` and write values into a (`index`,`column`) pair?

I do the  following in Python with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['Maria', 'John'], columns = ['consumption','age'])
df.loc['Maria']['age'] = 52
```

I would like to do the same in Julia. How can I do this? The [documentation](https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) shows a DataFrame similar to the one I would like to construct but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Maybe [NamedArrays.jl](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @DanGetz Thank you that is a good idea.

Comment: I don't know that DataFrames.jl supports row indexes (other than by number).
There is [Pandas.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Pandas.jl) though.

Comment: @LyndonWhite thank you for your comment. I didn't know pandas is accessible within Julia; I'm glad it is and will try it.